# Android SDK help (java)

Tags: java, android, random, numbers

So I'm really not too great at programming, but I am reading and trying to change that, for the time being i need some help.  I have a simple app that will generate 7 random numbers 1-49 and place those 7 numbers in a text box.  I just need help with the for loop that does this, what i have so far is code/pseudo code.

```
String str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
```

generate ... random code 
  array to keep track of random numbers generated so no collisions occur
  method call that goes through the array then keep looping

```
str += random + "_" ;
txtTextBox.settext(str);
```

Comment: Did you try this code?

Comment: Post real code so we can see where the problems may be.

Comment: well, before i answer, is making apps for android essentially the same, with some differences? so for example, if i were to use a random number generator, i would usually use `Random r = new Random();`. so would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something like this

```
String str = "";

Random rand = new Random();

for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
    str += (rand.nextInt(49) + 1) + " ";
}

txtTextBox.setText(str);
```

Comment: hey this worked great, thank you! basically used this code to output it to the text box and it works excellent

Answer (score 0):

Well here's how random works: and included in what I think your code is.

First you need your random number:`Random r = new Random();` and then the code for it to generate your numbers `r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;` (This will include your min and max numbers) Now add this to your code. Something like this:

```
 Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        str += r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }
txtTextBox.settext(str);
```